# How can I make automaton that has given language?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

[image]

I am trying to solve above question, below is the automaton I came up with:

[image]

Is there any ways to define automaton without having marked states?

Comment: In this context, is "mark" supposed to be a synonym for "accept"?

Comment: If "marked" means "accepting", then an automaton with no accepting states accepts no strings. That's a valid automaton, but it accepts the language $\emptyset$, which isn't the language you're trying to accept, here.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: @dkaeae: I think so

Comment: @DavidRicherby Can you please explain why it would explain a null string ?My first marked state is after "b" , should smallest string be b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make an automaton that accepts the language 
$L_1 = \{ s \in \{a, b\} \mid \text{each $a$ in $s$ is immediately preceded and followed by }b \}$.

A few examples of words that should be accepted are:

- $\lambda$ , which is the empty word. There is no $a$ in the empty word so this word should be accepted.
- $b^*$, which is any word only containing $b$'s.
- Other examples: $bab$, $bbbbbab$, $babababab$.

So let's start constructing. Since the empty word is accepted, the initial state $q_0$ should be an accepting state. A word starting with $a$ can't be accepted, therefore we forward such a word to $q_3$ and let it be stuck there. $q_3$ is not an accepting state.

Now consider a word starting with $b$. The word $b$ should be accepted, so $q_2$ is an accepting state. $b^*$ should be accepted, therefore we define the transition function $\delta(q_2, b) = q_2$. (Any $b$ in $q_2$ goes to $q_2$.)

Now the transition from $q_2$ to $q_4$ is triggered by an $a$. $q_4$ is not an accepting state. If there is another $a$, we know that the input should not be accepted so we define the transition $\delta(q_4, a) = q_3$. Once in $q_3$ it will loop there, so the word can't be accepted.

The transitions between $q_2$ and $q_4$ make sure that any word ending with b is accepted, provided that a sequence of multiple $a$s never occurs. If it does it will go to state $q_3$ and it will be stuck there.

[image]

Comment: Also, please bear in mind that we don't want to be a homework cheating site. You probably just did somebody's homework for them.

Comment: Can you please explain how it works? As I can see event at some instances "a" can be followed by "a"(State q3 and q4) which conflicts with the language defined

Comment: @Siddhesh I think you need to revise how automata work. The automaton has to be able to _read_ all strings, but it should only _accept_ strings in the language.

Comment: Good point. I will update the answer once I am back home (:

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: @KAbdulahi Much better! Thanks! I made a small edit to correct a mistake you made a couple of times. You'd said "language" where you mean "word", "string" or "input". Remember that a language is a set of words; you were talking about the specific word that's the input to the automaton.

Comment: Can't you just define $\delta(q_4, b) = q_2$ and drop $q_5$ altogether?

Comment: @Arth You are right. That would accept the same language.